# Projects with same nuget package referencing different version of assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, assembly-binding-redirect

I am going mad here, and I am hoping that it's something that I've simply overlooked.

I am experiencing intermittent `FileLoadExceptions`, which are showing up after deployments even if the code change between deployments **doesn't change any assembly references**.

Looking at the most recent example of this, I am seeing a `FileLoadException` due to `System.IO.Compression`, version `4.2.0.0` not being found.

In all cases, we are referencing the `System.IO.Compression` nuget package, version `4.3.0`.

Looking at two projects in our solution, I noticed something very strange.
`ProjectA` references `ProjectB`.

`ProjectA` has in its `packages.config` file the following reference:

```
<package id="System.IO.Compression" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
```

`ProjectB` has in its `package.config` file the following reference:

```
<package id="System.IO.Compression" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
```

When I have a look into the `*.csproj` files, I see this:

`ProjectA`:

```
<Reference Include="System.IO.Compression, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\System.IO.Compression.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.IO.Compression.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>`
```

`ProjectB`:

```
<Reference Include="System.IO.Compression, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\System.IO.Compression.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.IO.Compression.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>`
```

Great, we are pointing to the same assembly on disk in both cases.

Yet, when I look at the referenced file in the Solution Explorer, I see this:

`ProjectA`:

[image: Reference to some other System.IO.Compression assembly]

The above is referencing a file that's in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.IO.Compression.dll`, and more importantly has a version of `4.2.0.0`, rather than the version that's in the nuget packages folder.

`ProjectB`:

[image: Reference to the correct System.IO.Compression assembly]

The above correctly points to the nuget packages version of the assembly, which is in fact `4.1.2.0`.

To reiterate, `ProjectA`, which references `ProjectB`, and both have a a binding redirect that's doing the following:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.IO.Compression" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.2.0" newVersion="4.1.2.0" />
</dependentAssembly>`
```

So my question is why is Visual Studio pulling down a version of `System.IO.Compression` from a location that **is not** referenced (directly) by any of our projects?  And, what can I do to fix this?

Further, while locally I am using the (current) RC version of Visual Studio 2019, our build agents (Azure DevOps Pipelines) are using Visual Studio 2017.

At runtime, we find the aforementioned exception logged, and our processing that creates a ZIP file fails.

**Update**

Further to the above, I've done some additional digging, and found a binding redirect that points to the `4.2.0.0` version of this assembly.  I've dropped that manually down to `4.1.2.0`, and am deploying again to our test environment with some additional health checks to see how we go.

Still remaining to understand how we would have gotten into this state, and why the discrepancies with what the `csproj` is pointing to vs. what is seen in the Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Projects with same nuget package refrencing different version of assembly

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25773) when we build a .NET Framework 4.6.x app.

That because:

> This is due to the **injected support for NETStandard 2.0. We inject new
>   assemblies into NET 4.6.1 and later desktop projects in order to add
>   support for netstandard2.0**. We do this in targets now instead of
>   packages because its no longer a requirement to reference a package to
>   build a netstandard library. This injection happens whenever we see a
>   netstandard1.5 or greater library referenced (see dotnet/sdk#1386).

To resolve this issue, we could add binding redirect to those reference to use standard references to `System.IO.Compression` and not bring in any Nuget package for `System.IO.Compression`. If you still want to use the reference `System.IO.Compression` from nuget package, you can delete `System.IO.Compression` from the MSBuild tooling.

Check more detail info from the Github:

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25773

Hope this helps.

Comment: Alright - thanks for the details.  I presume that if we upgraded everything to .NET 4.7 this issue could go away?  I am checking into whether or not Azure App Services and Cloud Services support that version of .NET.

Comment: @BrendanGreen, AFAIK, this issue still occurred on the  .NET 4.7.1. And .NET 4.7.2 helps with some but not all of these, check info from here: https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/481#issuecomment-429653699. And Hosted VS2017 support .net 4.7.1: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/master/images/win/Vs2017-Server2016-Readme.md#visual-studio-2017-enterprise

Comment: And to clarify, this makes sense as when I look back, we started a process of converting bits of the solution to .NET Standard 2.0, which I am starting to think is when this problem started cropping up.  Thanks for the additional references - I have some stuff to look into now...

Comment: @BrendanGreen, You are always welcome :). Please let me know if you would like further assistance.