# Add NuGet references to System.IO.Compression, System.IO.Compression.ZipFile, but compiler uses Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions folder?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

These are the references in the csproj,

```
<Reference Include="System.IO.Compression, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\packages\System.IO.Compression.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.IO.Compression.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.IO.Compression.FileSystem" />
<Reference Include="System.IO.Compression.ZipFile, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\packages\System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

it refuses to use those files and instead grabs the ones that are different versions from here

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.IO.Compression.dll

and here

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll

Any idea why it's doing that? If I remove the NuGet references and use the dll's directly then I get build errors with classes existing in the same namespace but different assemblies.

Comment: Can your share the error details and failing code?

Comment: When you look at the project reference properties window for the references, they point to those folders and not the NuGet packages folder. The wrong dll's are being used despite the hintpath provided.

Comment: Oops, it's tricky to find but this question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55037565/projects-with-same-nuget-package-referencing-different-version-of-assembly)